# stuck at URL patterns of django

Tags: regex, python-2.7, django-urls, django-1.3

Hi I am using following URL patterns in django and I am wondering that where is problem and why it is not able to find it. Following screenshot shows my URL as well as expected URLs.
[image]

Please tell that where I am making mistake. Please tell if some thing else I can tell to understand problem. I was looking on it for almost an hour or 2 and then I posted it on stackoverflow.com so hope I will get some solution.

Adding urls.py here:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url 
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'ecomstore.views.home', name='home'),
#url(r'^catalog/', 'preview.views.home'),

# url(r'^ecomstore/', include('ecomstore.foo.urls')),
# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
 url(r'',include('catalog.urls')),
  )
```

Then urls.py of catalog app:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
urlpatterns=patterns('catalog.views',
    (r'^$','index',{'template_name':'catalog/index.html'},'catalog_home'),
    (r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$','show_category',{'template_name':'catalog/category.html'},'catalog_category'),
    (r'^product/(?P<product_slug>[-_\w+])/$','show_product',{'template_name':'catalog/product.html'},'catalog_product'),
```

)

thanks in advance guys.

Comment: can you type out the text of your urlconf instead of a screenshot? I can't read it, but I bet there's something wrong with the 4th line of it.

Comment: I have tried removing it but facing same issue

Comment: tried removing what? The slash, or the line? You need the line so django can match it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

referring to my comment: at least one thing wrong is that you have an extra slash before "product". You want ^product, not ^/product. That might be all but it's a little hard to tell from the pic.

also, correct me if I'm wrong, because I haven't used regexes in a while, but doesn't [-_\w+] only match - OR _ OR \w+?

"[ ]

Match anything inside the square brackets for ONE character position once and only once, for example, [12] means match the target to 1 and if that does not match then match the target to 2 while [0123456789] means match to any character in the range 0 to 9."

http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm

so you'd want... [-_]\w+ ?

Comment: can you post the text of your urlconf?

Comment: answer updated. I'm assuming it doesn't notify you, since it didn't notify me when you updated your question.

Comment: I think it shouldn't matters if it match with - or _ or a alphanumeric so I think it shouldn't create problem in matching, it can match to any of these and more than one instances

Comment: I meant exclusive or. Are you sure about it being more than one instance? What happens if you change it to [-_]\w+?

Comment: I guess more like \w+[-_]\w+, actually, because you have stuff before and after your underscore.

Comment: Yes actually correct answer, I was doing this typo error: [-\w+] instead of [-\w]+ was error. thanks for your time Colleen.